# convergence of a "nice " subseries of a divergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

$$S_0 := a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$$ is a divergent series of positive terms whose limit approaches 0. Obtain a subseries $$S_1 := b_1+b_2+b_3+\cdots$$ from $S_0$ by deleting all terms with **even** subscripts. If it is not convergent obtain a subseries $S_2$ from $S_1$ by deleting all terms with **even** subscripts. If not convergent, continue the process until you get a convergent series.
Is there always an nth stage when we have achieved a convergent series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Counterexample:** take $a_n = \frac 1{n}$.  At the $k$th step, we have something like $a_n = \frac 1{kn}$.